# Getting error while creating Trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created a trigger below but its giving me error as

`3/1       PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement 5/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 6/28      PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here Errors: check compiler log`

Below is my code

```html
create or replace TRIGGER "APP_WFM"."TRG_INS_NE_SF_SITE_INSTANCE" 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON NE_SITE_INSTANCE
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

select rf_siteid, sap_id, site_name from SF_NE_DETAILS;

INSERT INTO NE_SITE_INSTANCE (rf_siteid, sap_id, sitename)
VALUES (rf_siteid, sap_id, site_name);

END;
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: The error looks pretty clear- you have a `select` statement but you're not doing anything with the data.  If you expect the `select` to return a single row, you could do a `select into` three local variables.  If you expect the `select` to return multiple rows, you'd need to select the data into collections or otherwise do something with the data (open a cursor, use it to insert data).  I'm not sure what you intend the trigger to do, though, since you then try to `insert` a row into the table that caused the trigger to fire.  That would create an infinite loop.

Comment: @hud, what do you want to recover from the select exactly ? you are selecting all the values in one table to insert all of them into NE_SITE_INSTANCE, but that would happen for each row. Try to explain the logic you want to implement, thereby we might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous question, you want to use the `:NEW` record to get the inserted values and then insert into the second table that you are copying into:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER APP_WFM.TRG_INS_NE_SF_SITE_INSTANCE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON NE_SITE_INSTANCE -- Table being copied from
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SF_NE_DETAILS ( -- Table being copied to
    rf_siteid,
    sap_id,
    site_name
  ) VALUES (
    :NEW.rf_siteid,
    :NEW.sap_id,
    :NEW.site_name
  );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc9565849a254c8456a50717c025017d)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer MT0, can we trace any error for some reason if the data is not inserted in this ? Or we can log in table. any suggestion ?